# How to specify s3 bucket region

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I looked online, we have an s3 bucket with name:

```
nixos-build
```

so supposedly this is the url

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/nixos-build
```

but don't we have to specify the AWS region? how do we put that in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bucket names are in the format:

```
http://BUCKETNAME.s3-REGION.amazonaws.com
```

Examples:

```
http://mybucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
http://my.bucket.name.has.dots.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
http://invoices.s3.amazonaws.com   (Defaults to us-east-1, can involve redirects to other regions)
```

Note the period after the bucket name and the dash in the `s3-REGION` portion.

There is also an older format:

```
http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket
```

However, that format is being deprecated. See: [Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan – The Rest of the Story | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the URL which should get created:

https://BucketName-REGION.s3.amazonaws.com/KeyName

Comment: thanks, I wonder if the bucket and region can go in path or query params too?

Comment: We do use bucket name and key name in a various environment variables and other parameters too.

Comment: I am not sure if this is right, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380939/how-to-specify-s3-bucket-region/57382257#57382257

Comment: URL that I have given you is what exactly I see on my console right now for a bucket. Let me check the documentation.

Comment: Refer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

Comment: @Pacifist_AWS There should be a period after the bucket name, not a dash.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be:

http://bucket.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com

which is documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

Comment: There should be a dash after `s3`